# Handling old messages when a newer one has already been processed spring kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, domain-events

Today, for example, if I deactivate a product, I launch an event (version 5), if immediately afterwards I launch an activate product (version 6), and when inventory processes this to "deactivate" the stock, it fails to process version 5, sending it to the retry threads and process 6, now if it processes 5, it will generate an inconsistent state, how could I store it and what is the best way to validate that this problem will not happen?